# Why does repeating an equation help in FindRoot?

Tags: equation-solving

I'm trying to understand this behavior of `FindRoot`. Consider a sample function (the one I'm actually interested in is far more complicated, but has similar issues) and the following arguments:

```
crazyFunction[x_, y_] := N@Norm[{x + 2 y}]
yact = RandomReal[{-10, 10}, 2]~Join~{RandomReal[{100, 250}]};
gv = yact + RandomReal[{-.1, .1}, 2]~Join~{RandomReal[{-5, 5}]};
sampledata = crazyFunction[#, {a, b, c}] == crazyFunction[#, yact] & /@
 {{1, 2, 3}, {2, 3, 4}, {4, 5, 6}};
```

Basically, I'm applying the sample function for a particular `yact` value, at three `x` values, and setting it equal to the function evaluated with three "unknown" `y` values `{a,b,c}`. To solve for the "unknown" values, I used `FindRoot` with initial guessed value `gv` randomly perturbed from the actual values:

```
sol = FindRoot[sampledata, Transpose@{{a, b, c}, gv}, MaxIterations -> 1000]
```

Note, this likely will throw a warning `(* FindRoot::lstol: The line search decreased the step size to within tolerance specified by AccuracyGoal and PrecisionGoal ... *)`.

To evaluate the quality of the solution, I compare the `Norm` of the difference between the actual `yact` and the solved `y` (normalized to the `Norm` of `yact`):

```
Norm[yact - {a, b, c} /. sol]/Norm[yact]
(* Out[]:= 0.0540657 *)
```

which isn't a terrible value.

My thinking here is, I have three unknowns -- `a`, `b`, and `c` -- and three different equations for the different `x` values, so that should be enough to solve the problem. In fact, without three equations `FindRoot` won't work. I.e.:

```
FindRoot[sampledata[[1]], Transpose@{{a, b, c}, gv}, MaxIterations -> 1000]
(* FindRoot::nveq: The number of equations does not match the number of variables in... *)
```

But, if instead of using three, different equations, I simply repeat the same equation three times:

```
sampledata = Table[crazyFunction[#, {a, b, c}] == crazyFunction[#, yact] &@{1, 2,3}, {3}];
sol = FindRoot[sampledata, Transpose@{{a, b, c}, gv}, MaxIterations -> 1000];
```

Not only does it not give the `lstol` warning, but it actually gets a more accurate result! Consider:

```
dat=Table[yact=RandomReal[{-10,10},2]~Join~{RandomReal[{100,250}]};
 gv=yact+RandomReal[{-.1,.1},2]~Join~{RandomReal[{-5,5}]};
 sampledata=crazyFunction[#,{a,b,c}]==crazyFunction[#, yact]&/@{{1,2,3},{2,3,4},{4,5,6}};
 sol=Quiet@FindRoot[sampledata,Transpose@{{a,b,c},gv},MaxIterations->1000];
 Norm[yact-{a,b,c}/.sol]/Norm[yact],{1000}];

datSamedata=Table[
 yact=RandomReal[{-10,10},2]~Join~{RandomReal[{100,250}]};
 gv=yact+RandomReal[{-.1,.1},2]~Join~{RandomReal[{-5,5}]};
 sampledata=Table[crazyFunction[#,{a,b,c}]==crazyFunction[#, yact]&@{1,2,3},{3}];
 sol=Quiet@FindRoot[sampledata,Transpose@{{a,b,c},gv},MaxIterations->1000];
 Norm[yact-{a,b,c}/.sol]/Norm[yact],{1000}];

Histogram[{dat, datSamedata}, "Log"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Note the log-binning. Using the same equation three times is far more accurate than using three different equations!

So, my question is: **Why is repeating the same equation three times far more accurate than using three different equations?**

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o-K-LdB4XgQ

Comment: It strikes me that tripling the equations must (at least) triple the number of function evaluations during the search. For the comparison to be fair, then, you need to triple the number of iterations used with the single set of equations.  (I wouldn't be surprised if, in that light, tripling the equations is found to be inferior in accuracy.)

Comment: If you prepend a `SeedRandom[3]` to your first block of code, then you will consistently generate the lstol error, rather than just "likely" generate it.

Comment: I'm not certain about this but, if you apply a 2D Newton's method to an redundant system, you'll find that it reduces to an essentially 1-dimensional iteration.  Thus, perhaps, it's not surprising that we get more precision.

Comment: @whuber I don't understand your point. In principle, you need three equations to solve for the three unknowns.

Comment: @MarkMcClure So you're thinking it's just an extensive 1D iteration? It's not obvious to me that 1D iteration yields higher precision.

Comment: @EliLansey Yes, that's what I'm thinking. Whether this indeed yields higher precision is exactly the part that's not clear to me either.  Seems like a possibility, though.

Comment: @MarkMcClure I would've figured that for the same number of iterations a higher-dimensional approach would be better, though.

Comment: I also agree with whuber's point that the number of function evaluations should be considered in the evaluation of efficiency.

Comment: @MarkMcClure but there are *always* three function evaluations.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/5902/discussion-between-eli-lansey-and-mark-mcclure)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's one way to think about the 2D Newton's method, which explains why a 2D Newton's method applied to a redundant system can lead to the exact result after just one step.  Some variant of this is likely used by `FindRoot`.

We want to find the roots of a two by two system.  Start with an initial guess $(x_0,y_0)$, set up linear approximations to each equation, and solve the two by two *linear* system that results to improve the guess.  Suppose, for example, we want the simultaneous roots of the following system.

```
f[x_, y_]  := x^3 - 2 y;
g[x_, y_]  := y^3 - 2 x;
```

It's easy to see that the solutions are $(x,y)=(0,0)$ or $(x,y)=(\pm\sqrt{2},\pm\sqrt{2})$.

Here's the general solution of the corresponding linear system.

```
fx[x_, y_] := D[f[x, y], x];
fy[x_, y_] := D[f[x, y], y];
gx[x_, y_] := D[g[x, y], x];
gy[x_, y_] := D[g[x, y], y];
{sol} = Solve[{
  f[x0, y0] + fx[x0, y0] (x - x0) + fy[x0, y0] (y - y0) == 0,
  g[x0, y0] + gx[x0, y0] (x - x0) + gy[x0, y0] (y - y0) == 0}, 
{x, y}];
sol
```

[image]

This suggests that we iterate the following function.

```
newt[{x_, y_}] = {
  (2*(3*x^3*y^2 + 2*y^3))/(-4 + 9*x^2*y^2),
  (2*(2*x^3 + 3*x^2*y^3))/(-4 + 9*x^2*y^2)
};
NestList[newt, {1.0, 1.0}, 5]

(* Out *)
{{1., 1.}, {2., 2.}, {1.6, 1.6}, {1.44225, 1.44225}, 
 {1.41501, 1.41501}, {1.41421, 1.41421}}
```

Looks good.

OK, now let's do it for a redundant system.

```
f[x_, y_]  := x^3 - 2 y;
g[x_, y_]  := x^3 - 2 y;
```

Any point of the form $(x,x^3/2)$ is a solution.  Let's try Newton's method.

```
fx[x_, y_] := D[f[x, y], x];
fy[x_, y_] := D[f[x, y], y];
gx[x_, y_] := D[g[x, y], x];
gy[x_, y_] := D[g[x, y], y];
{sol} = Solve[{
  f[x0, y0] + fx[x0, y0] (x - x0) + fy[x0, y0] (y - y0) == 0,
  g[x0, y0] + gx[x0, y0] (x - x0) + gy[x0, y0] (y - y0) == 0}, 
 {x, y}];
sol
```

[image]

This suggests that we iterate the following function.

```
newt[{x_, y_}] = {x, x^3/2};
```

And we get to the exact solution after one step.

Comment: Very interesting. This should hold true for systems with (many) complex variables, too, right?